# EV3 Port 1 connection issue

Tags: ev3

Port 1 on one of our EV3s is acting up.  The port recognizes a sensor if the sensor is connected when powering up the unit, but if you unplug the sensor and plug it back in, the EV3 no longer recognizes a sensor at port 1.  All other ports work.  The issue is not wires or the sensors themselves as I've tried with different wires and different sensors.

It is still possible to use the port, but needed to shut down and restart if we want to change out the port 1 sensor is a hassle.

Anyone have thoughts on fixing this.
Firmware is 1.09E.  We use Education Ev3 Classroom.

Thanks